# Case Sensitivity in google spreadsheet queries

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I just want to use a query in google spreadsheet that is not case sensitive on a string with regular cell reference. So here is what I do:

```
=QUERY(Website!$A16:$D, "select B WHERE (C='"&$B$1&"' OR B contains '"&$B$1&"')", -1)
```

So B1 obviously contains the String I am looking for. Unfortunately both "=" and "contains" are somehow case sensitive. Do you have an idea to work around that?

Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the lower() function:

```
=QUERY(Website!$A16:$D, "select B WHERE (lower(C)=lower('"&$B$1&"') OR lower(B) contains lower('"&$B$1&"'))", -1)
```

NOTE: If you will possibly get a non-text cell, lower() will fail.

Comment: Yepp this did the trick. A lot of "lowers" though. Isn't there a way to just capsule the whole thing in "lower()"?